# How to interact with Strapi Menus plugin?

Tags: strapi

I've installed `strapi-plugin-menus` after restart the server I can't see anything on the admin sidebar. But the documentation shows there should be a Menus page link after Media Library.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm stupid This is not an issue.
After installing any plugin that needs to interact with the admin panel, I just ran `npm run build` and then restarted the server `npm run develop`.

That's it.